# Remoting client server asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this code in the server side.

```
   public DataTable DIS(int IID)
   {
      SqlConnection con = new 
      SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ADP_C1ConnectionString);
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Paper";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      DataTable DT = new DataTable();
      SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      DA.Fill(DT);
      con.Close();
      return DT;
   }
```

I want to make the grid view in the client side take its source from that function like this:

```
public void dis_data()
{
    DataTable DT = mgr.DIS(JouranlIID);
    sda.Fill(DT);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now? Are you getting an error? How does it not work as expected? Why are you using a DataTable instead of strongly typed objects? Do you know what [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) is?

Comment: show html tag for your dataGridView1 which you have placed in your .aspx page